# Spanning tree problem

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I am trying to solve a problem in graph theory that has the following setting: Let $T$ be a forest on the vertex set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with components $T_1,\ldots, T_k$. I need to prove that the number of spanning trees on the **complete graph** on the vertex set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ that contain $T$ is $n^{k-2}\prod_{i=1}^k |T_i|$. I don't really understand what the spanning tree of a disjoint union of trees on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ would be. Can someone help me visualise what I am supposed to count?

Comment: Spanning trees don't exist for disconnected graphs...

Comment: This is precisely my problem. A forest is disconnected, in general.

Comment: Well that's the answer. There is no spanning tree.

Comment: I'm guessing, perhaps, rather than remove edges to form a spanning tree, you're supposed to add edges to form a spanning tree? The usage of the term "spanning tree" seems unconventional here, but that might be the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: Made an edit that makes this into a sensible statement. Note that it is trivially true if $k=1$, the general case looks reasonable as well. Roll back the edit if that is not what you meant.

Comment: @quarague Great edit. Definitely saved the question.

Comment: @quarague the solution to this problem suggests to count how many trees contain an edge between two components of T. Does this add up with your edit?

Comment: For $k=2$ one can get a spanning tree of the entire vertex set by connecting any vertex from one tree to any vertex from the other tree. This gives exactly $|T_1|\cdot|T_2|$ possibilities as in the formula. I don't quite see how to generalize to arbitrary $k$, maybe an inductive proof, either on $k$ or on $n$.

Comment: @quarague Ok, and this would be without requiring that the spanning trees are on the complete graph (your edit)?